# PHP, file_exsist() in Windows on shared network

Tags: php, windows, iis

When I run the PHP command `file_exsist()` on a file in a shared network on Windows I always get false even though the file exists. I believe this could be because of permissions?

Can I run the `file_exsist()` command as different permissions?
I can not change the ApplicationPool authentication as the PHP page must be run as a different user.

```
$fileexsist = file_exists("W:\\foo");
```

Comment: try to use the network path `\\\\server\\dir\\foo`

Comment: Please look at the PHP reference to see how to use file_exists on windows correctly. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php